# SyntaxError: while importing requests_html

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I attempt to import `requests_html`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests_html
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 13, in <module>
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\fake_useragent\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fake_useragent.fake import FakeUserAgent, UserAgent  # noqa # isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\fake_useragent\fake.py", line 10, in <module>
    from fake_useragent.utils import load, load_cached, str_types, update
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\fake_useragent\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, URLError
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib2.py", line 220
    raise AttributeError, attr
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help.

Comment: This is odd, because from your directories, you seem to be using Python 3. From looking at the code in the `fake_useragent` package (https://github.com/hellysmile/fake-useragent), the `urllib2` package should not be imported at all. Can you show us the output of `python --version`?

Comment: Thanks,but i solved the issue.The main issue was i was using python 3.8 version but somehow urllib2 was installed in it which is not supported by python 3.8. So i deleted the urllib2 package and it is working fine

Comment: But now i am facing another problem .You see whenever i try to import requests-html.And try to use html.render() from requests-html i get an error.I am the giving the sample code below

Comment: `from requests_html import HTMLSession                                                     
 session = HTMLSession()                                                                                        
  r= session.get('python.org/')                                                               
 r.html.render()

Comment: i get a timeout 
`pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 8000 ms exceeded.`

Comment: @tnwei pls help